# Will alkoxide ion in protic medium attack on double bond or carbonyl group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity

I want to know what will happen next here-[image]

I thought that the alkoxide ion would attack the aldehyde to form a secondary alcohol, but apparently, as the two pi-bonds are in conjugation, so, the ion attacks the carbon of the C-C pi-bond. Why is this so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your title should read "protic medium" as opposed to "acidic medium". Acidic medium would be EtOH/H<sup>+</sup>. Your reaction conditions are basic and protic.
 Nothing much will happen to the unsaturated aldehyde **1**. 1.2-Addition leads to hemiacetal **2**. Hemiacetals are unstable to base and reverse to the carbonyl compound. Adduct **3** would eliminate to form **1** in the presence of base. If you employed EtOH-d<sub>1</sub> as the solvent, you would incorporate deuterium at the γ-position of **1**-d<sub>2</sub> via enolate **4**. If heptanedial **5** were exposed to EtOK/EtOH, an aldol condensation would ensue to form unsaturated aldehyde **1**. Under truly acidic conditions, the diethyl acetal (in the red box) of aldehyde **1** would form. Formation of the β, γ-isomer of **1** is unlikely because the α, β-form **1** is much more stable.

[image]